# Modify Script to Close Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I've got a nice little show only one div at a time script working that I found at:
[Random Snippets](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/04/10/how-to-hide-show-or-toggle-your-div-with-jquery/) (second demo down) that looks like this:

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show(200);
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(600);
          }
     });
}
```

The only thing it doesn't do is close the div after you open it. Currently I have both divs set to display: none and would like to give the user the option to close them both when they are done looking.

Any idea's how to modify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a condition about the visibility of the current item in the `if` statement:

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone && $(this).css("display") == "none") {
               $(this).show(200);
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(600);
          }
     });
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Never would have been able to come up with that on my own so I thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a click event that closes them when clicked:

```
$('.newboxes').click( function() {
    $(this).hide(600);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a button or something to the user to close the divs. Let's assume there is a button like this inside each div:

HTML

```
<div class="div-class">
    <p>Box content</p>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.close').on('click', function() {
   $(this).closest('.div-class').hide();
});
```

Comment: I thought about the button idea but there is no easy place in the design to put it that won't look out of place. Thanks for this option though, I'll keep this one for use later.